# Alfresco: Stream is already closed

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, opencmis, apache-chemistry

I am trying to create text document using apache-chemistry in alfresco. My code is for creating document is

> Document document = FileUtils.createTextDocument("/", "test.txt", "test document", BaseTypeId.CMIS_DOCUMENT.value(), VersioningState.MAJOR, session);

when I execute my code I am getting following exception

> org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisConnectionException: Cannot access "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom/children?id=5717e8a0-61b2-4bcb-8a91-2f4b61ebfefa&versioningState=major": Stream is already closed!
>       at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.http.DefaultHttpInvoker.invoke(DefaultHttpInvoker.java:233)
>       at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.http.DefaultHttpInvoker.invokePOST(DefaultHttpInvoker.java:68)
>       at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.post(AbstractAtomPubService.java:713)
>       at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.ObjectServiceImpl.createDocument(ObjectServiceImpl.java:122)
>       at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionImpl.createDocument(SessionImpl.java:1165)
>       at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.FolderImpl.createDocument(FolderImpl.java:77)
>       at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.FolderImpl.createDocument(FolderImpl.java:460)
>       at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.util.FileUtils.createTextDocument(FileUtils.java:168)

Comment: Check out the following pages: https://chemistry.apache.org/docs/cmis-samples/samples/create-objects/index.html#creating-a-document
https://chemistry.apache.org/docs/cmis-samples/samples/content/index.html

Comment: try my example and give us a feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this worked fine for me

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
String serverUrl = args[0];
String username = args[1];
String password = args[2];
Session session = getSession(serverUrl, username, password);
Folder root = session.getRootFolder();
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
properties.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, BaseTypeId.CMIS_
DOCUMENT.value());
String name = "New Document (" + System.currentTimeMillis() +
").txt";
properties.put(PropertyIds.NAME, name);
List<Ace> addAces = new LinkedList<Ace>();
List<Ace> removeAces = new LinkedList<Ace>();
List<Policy> policies = new LinkedList<Policy>();
String content = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
ContentStream contentStream = new ContentStreamImpl("text.txt",
BigInteger.valueOf(content.length()),
"text/plain", new ByteArrayInputStream(content.
getBytes()));
Document newDocument = root.createDocument(properties,
contentStream, VersioningState.MAJOR, policies, addAces, removeAces,
session.getDefaultContext());
System.out.println(newDocument.getId());
}
```

Comment: Is there any problem @rish

Comment: thnx for reply, yes code is running fine, I have one question can I create a link of one folder to other folder in alfresco, just like creating shortcut of folder or document in windows machine. thnx again

Comment: open a new topic and i will try to help you, do not forget to give me a feedback about `Alfresco: Failed to create directory`

Comment: hi, thnx for your help. I posted this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38559841/create-shortcut-of-folder-or-document-in-alfresco]. please help