# Create shortcut of Folder or Document in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, opencmis, apache-chemistry

My requirement is to create shortcut of one folder or document into another folder. For example lets say I have a folder called A and in this folder I have many documents. Now I want to create shortcut of this folder into another folder name B. So basically I don't want to store same content in folder B, it's contains link or reference of folder A. Whatever change made in folder A, it has to be reflected to folder B also. So any one please help me how to do it alfresco using apache chemistry.

Comment: I've done something like that, but the problem is i worked with `javaEE` and i can give you a start to have an idea how to do it with your own language.

Comment: I am also using java only. please guide me how to do using java

Comment: Ok first i create a `database` with columns (Repository_id, Repository_name, Repository_path ...) and many others informations (note that my table store informations about `Folder` + `File`) and after that i used it as an image of my `alfresco`, it mean that rather than work with alfresco i only use it when i need to create a new `File` or new `Folder`. hope that help

Comment: something called **I:app:filelink** is there in apache-chemistry using java. But I don't know how to do?

Comment: wait i will tcheck in `Apache-chimistry`

Comment: thnx for your help, I got this from this post https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-api/howto-create-filelink-types-cmis-api-06072016-1600

Comment: Is it the answer ???  if yes please post it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118196/discussion-between-rish-and-yagami-light).